# Changing text color of ribbon button

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I'm having an issue in **VS2013-15** where my buttons' font colour is a shade of grey rather than black.

Here is what the buttons look like currently:
[image]

Some of the text seems to change to the desired colour when hovered over. However, some don't changed even when hovered:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How were you able to add images for buttons in your ribbon? Sorry, I am not answering your question. I am just curious about this, because I had a hard time figuring this one out for myself.

Comment: Try this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c067d63b-f03c-4f18-aea6-128230134daf/how-to-add-new-icons-to-be-used-on-ribbon?forum=vcmfcatl

Comment: That looks strange. Disabled text and normal text look the same. I see the same thing on my computer with Windows 7 theme. But the other themes are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it using Barmak's answer. The Windows 7 theme is the problem.

To fix, you have 2 options.

## Option 1

---

#### Change the theme your program uses

This is a lazy work around. Just switch your visual manager from `CMFCVisualManagerWindows7` to one of the other visual managers.

---

## Option 2

---

#### Override the `OnUpdateSystemColors()` function

First off you'll need a new class that inherits `CMFCVisualManagerWindows7`:

```
class Win7VM : public CMFCVisualManagerWindows7
{

};
```

Then you'll need to call `DECLARE_DYNCREATE` as the object is created dynamically at runtime.

```
class Win7VM : public CMFCVisualManagerWindows7
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(Win7VM);  
};
```

Next, you'll need to implement the class.

```
class Win7VM : public CMFCVisualManagerWindows7
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(Win7VM)

    virtual void OnUpdateSystemColors()
    {
        CMFCVisualManagerWindows7::OnUpdateSystemColors();
        m_clrRibbonPanelCaptionText = RGB(0, 0, 0);
    }
};
```

After that, you need to call `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE` separate to your class implementation, in global scope.

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(Win7VM, CMFCVisualManagerWindows7);
```

Finally, we need to change our usage of `CMFCVisualManagerWindows7` to that of our new class:

```
CMFCVisualManager::SetDefaultManager(RUNTIME_CLASS(Win7VM));
```

---