# Overriding OnUpdateSystemColors issue

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mfc, overriding

I'm trying to override a function in order to display the text on my ribbon bar in the desired color. See my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617320/changing-text-color-of-ccmdui-button) question for details on that.

I was able to find a work around, but it's not exactly what I'm after.

After doing some more digging, I found the problem and a better solution but I'm running into an error that I don't know how to fix.

My code is as follows:

```
#pragma once
#include "afxvisualmanagerwindows7.h"
class Win7VM : public CMFCVisualManagerWindows7
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(Win7VM)
public:
    virtual void OnUpdateSystemColors()
    {
        CMFCVisualManagerWindows7::OnUpdateSystemColors();
        m_clrRibbonPanelCaptionText = RGB(0, 0, 0);
    }
};
```

I'm trying to use this class like this:

```
CMFCVisualManager::SetDefaultManager(RUNTIME_CLASS(Win7VM));
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Severity    Code    Description                                                                                                                                         Project    File     
Error     LNK2001   unresolved external symbol "public: static struct CRuntimeClass * __stdcall Win7VM::GetThisClass(void)" (?GetThisClass@Win7VM@@SGPAUCRuntimeClass@@XZ)  KST7    C:\TFSTest\test\KST - NextVersion\KST\KST7\MainFrm.obj
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Read [the `DECLARE_DYNCREATE` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56302tyt.aspx), pay special attention about what it says about [`IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fsfk9dy.aspx).

Comment: When attempting to use
    IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(Win7VM, CMFCVisualManagerWindows7)
I get the error "Function 'CRuntimeClass* Win7VM::_GetBaseClass()' has already been defined or declared"

Comment: You didn't put the `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE` macro invocation 'in the header file, right? That will *define* the function in all source files that includes the header file.

Comment: If not in the header file, where should I put it? I was unable to split the declaration and implementation as in the.cpp file I get a lot of errors.

Comment: You need to put the `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE` macro invocation in a source file. The rest of the class implementation can still be inline in the class definition in the header file.

Comment: Calling IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(Win7VM, CMFCVisualManagerWindows7) just before I call CMFCVisualManager::SetDefaultManager(RUNTIME_CLASS(Win7VM)) yields 2 errors. 1. "member function "Win7VM::CreateObject" may not be redeclared outside its class" and 2. member Win7VM is inaccessible. I have made sure to include "Win7VM.h"

Comment: You can't put the implementation macro inside another function, it must be in the global scope. The implementation macro actually defines a member function (the `Win7VM::GetThisClass` function) and you can't do it in another function. You need to learn more about those macros, how they work, and read more MFC examples which shows how they are used.

Comment: That fixed all my errors, thank you for being so patient with me. And yes you're right, I do.